# Program simulating dictionary using file handling - part 2

Tags: c++, object-oriented, file-system, error-handling, boost

This is the new version of the dictionary program which I uploaded for reviewing [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48759/program-simulating-dictionary-using-file-handling).

I would be grateful if the program could be reviewed for all the points mentioned in the above link.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
#include<limits>
#include<ctime>

#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

// Will remove these in the future
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

#if BOOST_OS_LINUX // Linux
#define PLATFORM_CONFIG_PATH    (getenv("HOME")+string("/.dict_config.txt"))
#define PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND  "reset"

#elif BOOST_OS_WINDOWS // Windows
#define PLATFORM_CONFIG_PATH    (getenv("USERPROFILE")+string("\\My Documents\\dict_config.txt"))
#define PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND  "cls"

#else
#error "Untested platform"
#endif


class Dictionary
{

    /************************************************/
    /************* Private data members *************/
    /************************************************/

    // OS-dependent command to clear the terminal screen
    const string clearScreenCommand = PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND;

    // Path to the configuration file.
    // The configuration file stores the path to the dictionary file.
    const path configFilePath = PLATFORM_CONFIG_PATH;

    // The data structure for containing the dictionary word-meaning pairs in the memory
    // A "word" can be a multi-word string unlike what its name suggests
    // A meaning can be a multi-line string
    map<string, string> dict;

    // A file handle to the dictionary file
    fstream dictFile;

    // Path to the dictionary file.
    // The dictionary file stores the word-meaning pairs.
    path dictFilePath;

    // The data structure for holding the help keywords and their explanations
    map<string, string> helpMap;

    /****************************************************/
    /************* Private member functions *************/
    /****************************************************/

    // Empty the dictionary
    void Clear();

    // Display the contents of the dictionary "num" pairs at a time
    void Display( size_t num = 0 );

    // Retrieve the first word of the query string
    string FirstWord( const string& query );

    // Helper for the constructor
    // Initialize helpMap
    void InitHelp();

    // Helper for the constructor
    // Read the path to the dictionary file from the config file.
    void ReadDictFilePathFromConfigFile();

    // Helper for the constructor
    // Load the contents of the dictionary file.
    void ReadFromDictFile();

    // Input the meaning of a word
    string ReadMeaning();

    // Remove a word-meaning pair from the dictionary
    void Remove( const string& word );

    // Retrieve the second word of the query string
    string SecondWord( const string& query );

    // Helper for the constructor
    // Make sure that the configuration file is existing.
    // If it is not existing, then initialize it by writing to it the path to the dictionary file.
    void SetupConfigFile();

    // Helper for the constructor
    // Make sure that the dictionary file exists, if not then create a new one.
    void SetupDictFile();

    // Show the help menu
    void ShowHelp();

    // Show a random pair from the dictionary
    void TakeTest();

    // Utility function
    // Convert any type to its string representation
    template<typename T> string ToString( const T& obj );

public:

    /***************************************************/
    /************* Public member functions *************/
    /***************************************************/

    // Read the dictionary file-path from the config file and populate the map from it.
    Dictionary();

    // Write the dictionary map to the dictionary file
    ~Dictionary();

    // Perform the action associated with the reserved keyword
    void DoReserved( const string& query );

    // Add a word to the dictionary
    void Insert( const string& word );

    // Check if the query recieved is a keyword
    bool IsReserved( string query );

    // Input a query
    string ReadQuery();
};


/*******************************************************************/
/************* Private member function implementations *************/
/*******************************************************************/

void Dictionary::Clear()
{
    dict.clear();
    cout << "Dictionary cleared!!\n\n";
}

void Dictionary::Display( size_t num )
{
    cout << "\t\t\t" << "Number of entries = " << dict.size() << "\n";

    // Show all the word-meaning pairs at once
    if ( num == 0 )
    {
        num = dict.size();
    }

    size_t i = 1;
    for ( const auto& it : dict )
    {
        cout << i << "). " << it.first << "\n\n" << it.second << "\n\n";

        if ( ( i % num == 0 ) && i != dict.size() )
        {
            cout << "\t\tPress <Enter> to resume..";
            cin.get();  // Wait for the user
        }
        ++i;
    }
}

string Dictionary::FirstWord( const string& query )
{
    stringstream ss( query );
    string ans;
    ss >> ans;
    return ans;
}

void Dictionary::InitHelp()
{
    helpMap["help"] = "Show this help screen";
    helpMap["screen"] = "Clear screen.";
    helpMap["clear"] = "Delete all the entries in the dictionary.";
    helpMap["show"] = "Show all the entries in the dictionary. Usage - 'show [number of words at a time]'";
    helpMap["test"] = "Take a self-test by showing any randomly chosen word from the dictionary and making you guess its meaning.";
    helpMap["remove"] = "Remove a word. Usage - 'remove <word>'";
    helpMap["exit"] = "Exit after saving the dictionary safely to the file";
}

void Dictionary::ReadDictFilePathFromConfigFile()
{
    ifstream fin( configFilePath.string() );
    // This will happen if there is a race condition and some other process deletes the config file just after we close it above.
    if ( !fin )
    {
        const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in reading '" + configFilePath.string() + "' : " + strerror( errno );
        throw errorMsg;
    }

    cout << "Trying to read the path of the dictionary file from the config file." << endl;

    // Read the dictionary file path from the config file
    string dictFilePathString;
    getline( fin, dictFilePathString );
    dictFilePath = path( dictFilePathString );
    cout << "The path of the dictionary file is - " << dictFilePath << endl;
}

void Dictionary::ReadFromDictFile()
{
    cout << "Opening the dictionary file" << endl;

    dictFile.open( dictFilePath.string(), ios_base::in );
    if ( !dictFile )
    {
        const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in opening '" + dictFilePath.string() + "' : " + strerror( errno );
        throw errorMsg;
    }

    cout << "Reading the contents of the dictionary from the dictionary file." << endl;

    // Read the contents of the dictionary file and load it in the dictionary data structure
    string word, meaning;
    while ( getline( dictFile, word, '$' ) )
    {
        dictFile.get(); // Read the newline after word
        if ( ( !word.empty() ) && getline( dictFile, meaning, '$' ) && ( !meaning.empty() ) )
        {
            dict.insert( make_pair( word, meaning ) );
        }
        dictFile.get(); // Read the newline after meaning

        // Maybe we missed a '$' here or there
        if ( !dictFile )
        {
            const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in reading '" + dictFilePath.string() + "' : The dictionary is in an inconsistent state";
            throw errorMsg;
        }
    }
    dictFile.close();
}

string Dictionary::ReadMeaning()
{
    string meaning;
    cout << "\nEnter meaning -:\n";
    char c;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        cin.get( c );
        // If the character read is a newline and the previous character read was also a newline.
        if ( meaning.size() && meaning[meaning.size() - 1] == '\n' && c == '\n' )
        {
            break;
        }
        meaning += c;
    }
    if ( meaning.find( '$' ) != string::npos )
    {
        cout << "The input cannot contain '$'" << endl;
        meaning = "\n"; // so that Dictionary::Insert() ignores it
    }
    return meaning;
}

void Dictionary::Remove( const string& word )
{
    decltype( dict.begin() ) it;
    if ( ( it = dict.find( word ) ) != dict.end() )
    {
        dict.erase( it );
        cout << "'" << word << "' erased.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "'" << word << "' not found!\n";
    }
}


string Dictionary::SecondWord( const string& query )
{
    stringstream ss( query );
    string ans;
    ss >> ans >> ans;
    return ans;
}

void Dictionary::SetupConfigFile()
{
    cout << "The configuration file is not present.\nCreating a new configuration file.\n";

    // Create a new config file
    ofstream fout( configFilePath.string() );

    // If successful in creating the config file
    if ( fout )
    {
        cout << "Configuration file created successfully !\n";

        cout << "Enter the path to store the dictionary file -:\n";
        string dictFilePathString;
        getline( cin, dictFilePathString );
        dictFilePath = path( dictFilePathString );

        // Remove all symbolic links from the path
        try
        {
            dictFilePath = canonical( dictFilePath.parent_path() ) / dictFilePath.filename();
        }
        catch ( const filesystem_error& ex )
        {
            const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Dictionary path '" + dictFilePath.string() + "' not valid : " + ex.what();
            throw errorMsg;
        }

        // Write the dictionary file path in the config file.
        fout << dictFilePath.generic_string() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in creating '" + configFilePath.string() + "' : " + strerror( errno );
        throw errorMsg;
    }

    cout << "Path to the dictionary file successfully saved into the configuration file.\n";
}

void Dictionary::SetupDictFile()
{
    cout << "No dictionary file present." <<  endl;

    // Create a new dictionary file
    dictFile.open( dictFilePath.string(), ios_base::out );

    // If not successful in creating a new dictionary file
    if ( !dictFile )
    {
        const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in creating '" + dictFilePath.string() + "' : " + strerror( errno );
        throw errorMsg;
    }

    dictFile.close();
    cout << "New dictionary file created successfully!!" << endl;
}

void Dictionary::ShowHelp()
{
    cout << "\n";
    for ( const auto& it : helpMap )
    {
        cout << "'" << it.first << "' -- " << it.second << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Dictionary::TakeTest()
{
    if ( !dict.size() ) // Dictionary is empty
    {
        return;
    }

    decltype( dict.begin() ) it = dict.begin();
    advance( it, rand() % dict.size() );

    cout << "\t\t\t'" << it->first << "'\n\t\tPress <Enter> to show meaning..";
    cin.get();  // Wait for an "enter"
    cout << "\n\n" << it->second << "\n";
}

template<typename T> string Dictionary::ToString( const T& obj )
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << obj;
    return ss.str();
}

/******************************************************************/
/************* Public member function implementations *************/
/******************************************************************/

Dictionary::Dictionary()
{
    InitHelp();

    // If the configuration file does not exists, then setup the config file
    if ( !exists( configFilePath ) )
    {
        SetupConfigFile();
    }

    ReadDictFilePathFromConfigFile();

    // If the dictionary file does not exist
    if ( !exists( dictFilePath ) )
    {
        SetupDictFile();
    }

    ReadFromDictFile();

    // Open the dictionary file one last time for the duration of the object. It will be closed only in the destructor.
    dictFile.open( dictFilePath.string(), ios_base::out );

    // Should fail only in if some race-condition occurs
    if ( !dictFile )
    {
        const string errorMsg = "Line " + ToString( __LINE__ ) + " : Error in opening '" + dictFilePath.string() + "' : " + strerror( errno );
        throw errorMsg;
    }
}

Dictionary::~Dictionary()
{
    if ( exists( dictFilePath ) && dictFile )
    {
        cout << "Saving the dictionary's contents into the file" << endl;
        for ( const auto& it : dict )
        {
            // words and meanings both are terminated by "$\n"
            dictFile << it.first << "$\n" << it.second << "$\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "File saved!!" << endl;
}

void Dictionary::DoReserved( const string& query )
{
    string beforeSpace = FirstWord( query );
    string afterSpace = SecondWord( query );
    transform( beforeSpace.begin(), beforeSpace.end(), beforeSpace.begin(), ::tolower );

    if ( beforeSpace == "help" )
    {
        ShowHelp();
    }
    else if ( beforeSpace == "clear" )
    {
        Clear();
    }
    else if ( beforeSpace == "show" )
    {
        Display( atoi( afterSpace.c_str() ) );
    }
    else if ( beforeSpace == "screen" )
    {
        system( clearScreenCommand.c_str() );
    }
    else if ( beforeSpace == "test" )
    {
        TakeTest();
    }
    else if ( beforeSpace == "remove" )
    {
        Remove( afterSpace );
    }
}

void Dictionary::Insert( const string& word )
{
    decltype( dict.begin() ) it;

    string option;
    // Word already present in the dictionary
    if ( ( it = dict.find( word ) ) != dict.end() )
    {
        cout << "'" << it->first << "' already exists!!\n\n" << it->second << "\n\nWant to overwrite?? (y/n)  ";
        getline( cin, option );
        if ( option.size() && option[0] == 'y' )
        {
            string temp = ReadMeaning();
            if ( temp != "\n" )
            {
                it->second = temp;
                cout << "Definition of '" << word << "' updated!!" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "'" << word  << "' not added!" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    // New addition
    else
    {
        string temp = ReadMeaning();
        if ( temp != "\n" )
        {
            dict[word] = temp;
            cout << "New definition of '" << word << "' added!!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Word not added!" << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool Dictionary::IsReserved( string query )
{
    transform( query.begin(), query.end(), query.begin(), ::tolower );
    return helpMap.count( FirstWord( query ) );
}

string Dictionary::ReadQuery()
{
    string query;
    cout << "\nEnter query - ";
    getline( cin, query, '\n' );
    if ( query.find( '$' ) != string::npos )
    {
        cout << "The input cannot contain '$'" << endl;
        query = ""; // so that main() ignores it
    }
    return query;
}


/*****************************************************/
/************* Class definition ends *************/
/*****************************************************/


int main()
{
    try
    {
        srand( time( NULL ) );
        Dictionary dictionary;
        while ( 1 )
        {
            string query = dictionary.ReadQuery();
            if ( query.empty() )
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if ( query == "exit" )
            {
                break;
            }
            else if ( dictionary.IsReserved( query ) )
            {
                dictionary.DoReserved( query );
            }
            else
            {
                dictionary.Insert( query );
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( const string& errorMsg )
    {
        cerr << errorMsg << endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

A sample dictionary file:

> ```
> aberration$
> A deviation from the proper or expected course.
> $
> Back to the grind$
> Going back to work after a break.
> $
> abhor$
> To regard with horror or loathing; detest: "The problem with Establishment Republicans is they abhor the unseemliness of a
> political brawl" (Patrick J. Buchanan).
> $
> abhorrent$
> Inspiring disgust and loathing; repugnant
> $
> abide$
> remain
> $
> accoutrements$
> Additional items of dress or equipment, carried or worn by a person or used for a particular activity.
> A soldier's outfit other than weapons and garments
> $
> acquiescence$
> Passive assent or agreement without protest.
> $
> adjunct$
> 1. Something attached to another in a dependent or subordinate position. See Synonyms at appendage.
> 2. A person associated with another in a subordinate or auxiliary capacity.
> 3. Attached to a faculty or staff in a temporary or auxiliary capacity: an adjunct professor of history.
> $
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // Will remove these in the future 
> using namespace std;
> using namespace boost::filesystem;
>
> #if BOOST_OS_LINUX // Linux
> #define PLATFORM_CONFIG_PATH    (getenv("HOME")+string("/.dict_config.txt"))
> #define PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND  "reset"
>
> #elif BOOST_OS_WINDOWS // Windows
> #define PLATFORM_CONFIG_PATH    (getenv("USERPROFILE")+string("\\My Documents\\dict_config.txt"))
> #define PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND  "cls"
>
> #else
> #error "Untested platform"
> #endif
> ```

**A few points for the block above:**

- First issue here is exposing the full namespaces into the global scope right on the header file. Since you have even noted that it should be removed, then just do it. If you don't remove it at once, chances are you will just continue to use the names without namespace qualification forever. In case you haven't read this thread yet: [*Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1198654)
- Now the macros. It would be better, in my opinion, to declare a couple inline functions instead. For the `PLATFORM_RESET_COMMAND` it would also be better to wrap the `system()` call in a function as well, since there might not be an equivalent to a `system("cls")` on some other platform you might wish to support at some point in the future. What I would suggest:

  ```
  #if BOOST_OS_LINUX
      inline std::string getPlatformConfigPath() 
      {
          return getenv("HOME") + string("/.dict_config.txt");
      }

      inline void platformClearConsole()
      {
          system("reset");
      }

  // The rest ...
  ```

  Since we are talking about the `system()` function, it should be noted that this function is considered to be unsafe, since it might trigger the execution of an external untrusted process, so it might be used as an exploit. A program more concerned with data safety and security should never use this library function.
- One very minor thing, but those comments:

  ```
  #if BOOST_OS_LINUX // Linux
  ...
  #elif BOOST_OS_WINDOWS // Windows
  ...
  ```

  Are completely redundant, since the macro is already properly named.

**Other miscellaneous issues:**

- Your `ToString()` method is redundant with the Standard Library. Take a look at [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).
- I don't see any methods marked with `const`. Methods that don't change member data, such as your `ShowHelp()` can be marked with a `const` at the end to ensure [*const correctness*](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns).
- `decltype` in a place like this make the code too verbose, defeating the purpose of type inference:

  > ```
  > decltype( dict.begin() ) it = dict.begin();
  > ```

  Use [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) instead.
- Not the most idiomatic way to test for an empty container:

  > ```
  > if ( !dict.size() ) // Dictionary is empty
  > ```

  Use the `empty()` method instead and then remove the comment.
- Instead of throwing `std::string`, the usual convention is `throw` one of the standard exception classes provided by the C++ Library: [`<stdexcept>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept). You can also derive from one of those classes and define a more specific exception type to your application.
- In the big if/else-if chain on `DoReserved()`, you should consider providing a fallback `else` that throws an exception or just `assert`, to shield yourself from silently ignoring a bad input value.

---

### Separate data from presentation:

At the moment, your `Dictionary` class is more like a `DictionaryConsoleApp`. Both the dictionary lookup/management and user interface are crammed inside the same class. Not just that, but the class also does several other things, like file reading and writing. So the [*separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) is far from ideal.

What you should aim next, in my opinion, is to separate the actual work of a `Dictionary` from the UI and data presentation. A `Dictionary` should only provide methods to `lookup()` a word or string and return its definition, as well as possibly allow the caller to `define()` a new entry, as it is in your case.

If you make this separation, then you can create a Graphical User Interface without having to change a single line of code in `Dictionary`.